# Write a Python directory path string that contains both single and double back slash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, backslash, shutil

I know python prints strings containing backslash differently from the way it actually is. I do not care about print statements but I just want the string to begin with two back slashes and all the other slashes to be one slash like this:

```
\\xyz\abc\fish\orange
```

Currently, this is what I have coded and I get the error below:

```
import shutil

dir_path = r"\\xyz\abc\fish\orange"
print(dir_path)
shutil.copyfile("U:/Profile/Downloads/document1", dir_path)
```

I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\xyz\\abc\\fish\\orange'
```

I replaced the actual directory name with mock names but what's important is formatting the slashes. I would prefer to fix this issue while not using os library. Thank you.

Comment: Use forward slashes on *all* operating systems. Does using `os.path.exists(somepath)` cause some sort of problem for you?

Comment: check if the directory exists first. Also use friendly suggestion `pathlib` if you want to represent the paths properly regardless of the OS.

Comment: `r"\\xyz\abc" == '\\\\xyz\\abc'`, so what's the problem?

Comment: @JacobIRR we will be packaging it later into an executable so don't want to use too many libraries to memory

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy Tried pathlib but get same error

Comment: @wjandrea the name of the directory is \\xyz\abc\fish\orange

Comment: @Tawhid Yes, and Python represents that as `'\\\\xyz\\abc\\fish\\orange'`

Comment: Are you aware that backslash is the escape character in string literals?

Comment: The problem is that `copyfile` won't create any of the directories if they don't already exist, not with how you are representing the path.

Comment: @chepner how do I move  document 1 into the orange folder?

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy directory does exist using the os function

Comment: The destination argument must be the complete file name, not just the directory. `\\xyz\abc\fish\orange\document1`.

Comment: `copyfile` is mostly just a wrapper around `copyfileobj`, which passes both of its arguments to `open()` to get file objects suitable to pass to `copyfileobj`.

Comment: TawhidK: The `os` module is a standard Python module, so using `os.path` would likely not add much to the ultimate executable's size — it's probably being used by something else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```py
import shutil 
from pathlib import Path
dir_path = Path(r"\xyz\abc\fish\orange\document1") print(dir_path) 
if dir_path.exist():
    shutil.copyfile("U:/Profile/Downloads/document1", dir_path)
else:
    print(f"{dir_path} do not exist")
```

You can also catch the error.

```py
import shutil 
dir_path = r"\xyz\abc\fish\orange\document1" print(dir_path)
try: 
    shutil.copyfile("U:/Profile/Downloads/document1", dir_path)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"{dir_path} do not exist")
```